# Short Circuit of If Statement - How to evaluate

Tags: ios

Update:  This was all a wild goose chase.  After I made the changes based on a suggested answer, it worked.  However, when I tried it a bit later, it didn't work again.  What I've come to realize is it was all in how I was using the debugger.  I had a breakpoint inside areSameColor.  I assumed areUniqueColors wasn't being executed when I was stepping through the code.  However, I was stepping over the second condition and I assumed it was short-circuiting.  In the end, it was correctly evaluating with both options below.  I chose to stick with my 2nd example as it seemed more readable.  Thanks for everyone's time.

I'm confused at how the following if statement is evaluating...

```
    if(![self areSameColor:setCards] && ![self areUniqueColors:setCards]){
    match = NO;
}
```

in my test case [self areSameColor:setCards] evaluates to NO...so using ! I would expect it to evaluate the 2nd condition.  When watching the debugger, it seems to be shortcutting into a TRUE result.

I also tried with this:

```
if(!([self areSameColor:setCards] || [self areUniqueColors:setCards])){
    match = NO;
}
```

In both cases it's not evaluating the 2nd condition.  areSameColor and areUniqueColor return BOOL.

My expected evaluation...

```
areSameColor | areUniqueColor | MATCH
NO | NO | match = NO
YES | NO | match UNCHANGED
NO | YES | match UNCHANGED
```

How am I thinking of this wrong?

Comment: What are the expected result for areSameColor and areUniqueColors , Depending on which you want to set match flag..

Comment: In this case, areSameColor == NO and areUniqueColor == YES.  I would expect match = NO to be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this "*areSameColor == NO **and** areUniqueColor == NO*"
try this way

```
if( (![self areSameColor:setCards]) && (![self areUniqueColors:setCards]) )
{
    match = NO;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have clarified...if both areSameColor and areUniqueColor evaluate to NO, then match = NO.

Comment: Yep, looks like the placement of the parenthesis to force each ! to be evaluated independently for each condition.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the standard does not stipulate whether the not operator applied to the first operand does or does not trigger a short-circuit evaluation.  It stipulates && and ||, however, evaluated from left-to-right.  Unary operators (!) are generally evaluated right-to-left, prior to || and &&.

At the very least, the answer is sufficiently gray to warrant recoding it differently to avoid the whole mess.